# datareader error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a problem in selecting some data from a database and saving the data into a textbox. I have the following profile table:

[image: This is my table design]

```
if (Session["User"] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string user = Session["User"].ToString();
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SKRIPSI;User ID=sa;Password=sa");
                    conn.Open();
                    string biodata = "select * from mahasiswa where id='"+user+"'";
                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(biodata, conn);
                    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        txtid.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
                        txtnama.Text = reader["nama"].ToString();
                        txtemail.Text = reader["email"].ToString();
                        txtkontak.Text = reader["kontak"].ToString();
                        txtalamat.Text = reader["password"].ToString();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login_Form.aspx");
            }
```

According to my experience of coding this is correct. but I get an error when calling `while(reader.Read())`. This the error Exception.

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to data type int. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() at Skripsi.Mahasiswa.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Henz\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Skripsi\Skripsi\Mahasiswa.aspx.cs:line 26 ClientConnectionId:aebdd470-263a-43a9-a7f3-12885668d946 Error Number:245,State:1,Class:16`

Please help me solve this problem. I'm still a beginner. Thank You.

Comment: Post the logs of the error!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `while(reader.Read())` isn't error, can you add thrown Exception message

Comment: It seems to me you're comparing an int id to a string user...

Comment: The fifth column in your table is "alamat"; the code you posted is expecting "password".

Comment: its allowed null. so it won't be expecting

Comment: Read the error. Print the query to inspect it for yourself. Inspect your variables. `Session["User"]` is containing the string "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox". So the problem you're asking about is not the code causing this problem. Somewhere you're assigning the wrong value to `Session["User"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a single row, use if(reader.read()). while(reader.read()) could loop, and it often gets people into trouble when the query goes wrong.

You have nullable types in your database. You are not checking for null values though. Use the IsDBNull() method before you set the field. You have to go through an extra step as this only accepts an int.

```
if(!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("nama"))
{
    txtid.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
}
```

Also, in your sql statement you have single quotes around your id concatenation. The id column is defined as an int, adding it in single quotes will have it treated as a string.

```
 string biodata = "select * from mahasiswa where id="+user+"";
```

Keep in mind, this string concatenation approach ensures that your website is open to sql injection attacks, and the way it is written someone could easily craft sql that would give them the contents of the entire table, or even delete the contents of the database.